# Python runs faster with an editor open

Tags: python, pycharm, pyscripter

I am running a python script through a batch file:

```
..\tools\Python27\python.exe main.py
```

If I have some editor open (`PyCharm`, `pyScripter`, etc) my scripts runs faster. 
Anyone knows why? Any idea?

I tried to change the batch file to:

```
..\tools\Python27\python.exe -u main.py
```

And more parameter but the issue is not solved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the script run faster when PyCharm or PyScripter happen to be open in the background, or is it faster when you start the script *through* one of these IDEs?

Comment: Do you mean the script starts up faster, or is it actually executing faster the whole time?

Comment: And you said "etc.", for which other IDEs specifically have you observed this?

Comment: have you timed it using some standard method?

Comment: And does it happen for *any* script, or only for a particular one?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It happens when the IDE is open in background, my script is running through the batchfile. (It's very strange)

Comment: @tobias_k it is executing faster, I send CAN frames to a microcontroller at the maximum speed and I see the time between frames, and it is smaller when the IDE is open in background

Comment: @mkrieger1 I only tested with pyCharm and pyScripter, but I think is a process which is open in background in the IDE. I only test with my test script

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq I timed it sending CAN frames in a for loop, the speed is higher running on background the IDE

Answer (score 2):

There are really only three possibilities :

- Its a cacheing issue, either in the disk or in memory, that results in more efficient allocation when the script starts.
- Its an environment issue, where starting the editor adds some environment variables which give the python access to optimised libraries.
- Having an open editor changes which python is available on the path.

From what I can see its unlikely to be the first as that would give you a one time boost. Its unlikely to be the third because it looks like you are specifying the full path of the python.exe that you use, rather than just doing e.g. python main.py

Thus, its probable that starting the editor is adding extra library locations. This can happen if e.g. the editor is using a different python version. There are plenty of python libraries which will optionally delegate to certain optimised libraries if they are available. E.g. pandas delegates to numexpr if its installed for certain tasks. If its not installed it just uses less efficient pure python implementations. Thus adding a site location to your path by opening an editor could cause a program using pandas to speed up if it gives access to numexpr.

Try putting :

```
import site
import sys
print site.getsitepackages()
for x in sys.environ :
    print x
```

at the top of your script to look for differences in the environment.